# Create file within in the user selected directory using Chrome filesystem

Tags: google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

Is it possible to create a file with within the user selected directory using chrome.fileSystem. Is it something like the selected entry has access to entire directory and can perform create , read , delete operations ? I'm list the file paths within the selected directory.

```
 chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(theEntry) {
                    if (!theEntry) {
                      output.textContent = 'No Directory selected.';
                      return;
                    }
                    // use local storage to retain access to this file
                    chrome.storage.local.set({'chosenResultDir': chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(theEntry)});
                     ??? // writeNewFileTochosenResultDir(theEntry); // ?????
                  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry) documentation says the callback receives an `Entry`, which in case of `type: 'openDirectory'` is obviously a [DirectoryEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryEntry#getFile), so you can use [File API](https://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html) to create a file:

```js
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(entry) {
    entry.getFile('newfilename.txt', {create: true}, function(file) {
        file.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.write(new Blob(['hello'])); // async
            writer.onwrite = function(e) {
                writer.onwrite = null;
                writer.truncate(writer.position); // in case we overwrite an exitsing file
                console.log('Done', e);
            };
        }, function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

manifest.json minimum permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]}
],
```

An advanced example is available in the official [Chrome sample app repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can completely access the contents of the selected folder using the [web filesystem api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem) with the manifest permissions: {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]}